# Mac: Terminal Compiler Error on Server

Tags: c++, terminal, compiler-errors, server

How do I fix this? I am using Terminal on a server it gives me this compiler error when I try and run.

> ```
> flip2 ~/Assignment3 8% g++ characters.cpp
> In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/random:35,
>                  from characters.cpp:3:
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The output from g++ is telling you **exactly** what you need to do to fix this.

> **error** This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently
>   experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
>   compiler options.

So give it what it wants:

```
g++ -std=c++0x characters.cpp
```